# Librerias vs llamadas al sistema

Tags: java, python, linux

Estoy desarrollando un programa en Java/Python para únicamente sistemas 'UNIX'. Necesito hacer uso de utildades comunes en ambos lenguajes p.ej. obtener la ip local o la de la puerta de enlace (el ejemplo es irrelevante). Esto se puede resolver facilmente mediante comandos y hacendo la llamada desde el programa que lo necesite.

Algo como:

```
subprocess.call(["bash", "/scripts/get_local_ip.sh"]) # python
---
Process child = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("bash /scripts/get_local_ip.sh"); // Java
```

Pero entiendo que esto no es una buena prática.

¿Tengo alguna otra alternativa sin duplicar código? ¿En caso de no tener otra opción, si estas utlidades las programo en C, ganaré en eficiencia?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Primero, aclarar un tema de nomenclatura. Una llamada al sistema no es lo que aparentemente crees (según se deduce de tu pregunta). Entiendo que tú denominas "llamada al sistema" al hecho de ejecutar un comando a través de un shell (bash en este caso).

Técnicamente una llamada al sistema ([System call](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_call)) es otra cosa, algo más técnica, y es la forma en que un proceso en ejecución solicita un servicio al operativo, mediante un salto al *kernel* del mismo, que es quien se ocupa de realizar la tarea. Esto ocurre constantemente en cualquier programa que haga entrada/salida, por ejemplo. Cuando abres un fichero, ya que es el operativo quien controla los sistemas de fichero, sistemas de acceso, etc. la función `open()` en el fondo realiza una *llamada al sistema* (salto al kernel) que es quien realiza esa operación.

Las librerías (python o Java o lo que sea) están llenas de llamadas al sistema, pues es sólo el kernel el que tiene permisos para acceder al hardware.

Para no liar la nomenclatura entonces, denominaremos a lo que tú para ti eran "llamadas al sistema", "ejecución de comandos vía shell".

Ya que, como hemos visto, en el fondo todo pasa por una llamada al sistema (salto al kernel), la disyuntiva que tenemos es:

- Dejar que sea una librería la que lo haga
- Hacerlo a través de la ejecución de comandos vía shell

El principal problema de la segunda opción es la eficiencia, ya que se está dando un rodeo muy grande para llegar a lo que mismo. Cuando desde un programa (python o Java) quieres ejecutar un comando vía shell, ocurre lo siguiente:

1. Primero tienes que crea un subproceso, lo cual es una operación costosa en tiempo y memoria ya que, al menos en Unix, comienza por hacer un duplicado del proceso actual, para después dentro de él eliminar el código y cambiarlo por otro (en este caso, el del intérprete bash).

   Este primer paso ya implica una llamada al sistema, la de creación de procesos. Además implica acceso a disco para cargar el código de bash. Todo esto requiere tiempo y recursos.
2. Cuando bash arranca, lee una serie de archivos de configuración en los cuales se le indica el *path* (serie de carpetas en las que ha de buscar ejecutables), y en ellas buscará el comando que le solicitas. Una vez localizado, bash también crea un subproceso para ejecutar ese comando, con el consiguiente consumo de tiempo y recursos.
3. En caso de que lo que hayas cargado sea un *script*, cada línea del mismo es un paso como el anterior.
4. En algún momento el código que se ejecuta en el subproceso creado por bash (desde el subproceso creado por Python/Java), hará finalmente una *verdadera* llamada al sistema para obtener la información deseada (por ejemplo la IP de un interfaz de red)
5. La salida del comando será recogida por bash, y será mostrada en su salida estándar, la cual a su vez será recogida por Python. Esto implica también una comunicación entre procesos a través de descriptores de entrada/salida (más llamadas al sistema)
6. Finalmente la información deseada llega a Python/Java y el proceso que contenía bash será eliminado.

En cambio, si tienes una biblioteca (python o Java) que te dé la funcionalidad buscada, de todo lo anterior se haría únicamente el paso 4, ya que ese es el que realiza la llamada al sistema que obtiene la información requerida. No es necesario crear subprocesos, ni comunicarlos entre sí, ni cargar ejecutables de disco, etc. La cantidad de llamadas al sistema se reduce, y el tiempo de ejecución y los recursos de memoria necesarios, también.

Respecto a lo que dices de hacerlo en C, no ganarías gran cosa. La mayor parte del tiempo consumido no es debido a la llamada al sistema, sino a toda la creación de procesos y su comunicación, que sería necesaria igualmente para lanzar desde Python/Java tu programa C. A menos que estés pensando en hacer una extensión en C para python, pero ese es otro tema, que normalmente no es necesario porque las bibliotecas python que lo precisan ya están implementadas de ese modo.

Comment: ¿Por qué el voto negativo?

Comment: No te he votado yo negativamente que no tengo reputación ni para hacerlo positivamente como mereces. Muchas gracias por tu respuesta es justo lo que necesitaba y tienes razón que empleé mal el término de syscall.

Comment: @Nimda Ya suponía que no habrías sido tú, la pregunta era "al aire". Gracias por aceptar la respuesta.